# Nepomuk File Ontology

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

I want to  use [Nepomuk File Ontology (NFO)](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo/)  in a desktop software. Before starting I need some guidance on using NFO.

Forexample:

In NFO  we have **[File](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo/#FileDataObject)** class and **[Image](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo/#Image)** classes.

File Class properties are: *nfo:fileCreated, nfo:fileLastAccessed, nfo:fileLastModified, nfo:fileName, nfo:fileOwner, nfo:fileSize, nfo:fileUrl, nfo:hasHash, nfo:permissions*.

And Image Class properties are: *nfo:depicts, nfo:horizontalResolution, nfo:verticalResolution*

Now Please guide, I have an image file *i.e imagefile1.jpeg*  on which I want to apply properties of both File and Image classes.

which one of the below two methods is the correct method to do so.

- Method 1: Create a single Object i.e. *obj1* of type File and Image. So
  now I can annotate obj1  on properties of File class as well as Image
  Class.
- Method 2: Create two objects, one of type File i.e. *obj1* and second
  object of type Image i.e. *obj2*. and now link these two objects via
  [interpretedAs](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/01/19/nie/#interpretedAs) and [isStoredAs](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/01/19/nie/#isStoredAs) properties.

Please guide me which one is the correct approach so that I follow it in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "InformationElement is a piece of information stored within a data
>   object. Content-specific properties are defined as properties of an
>   InformationElement. It is separate from the DataObject in order to
>   make the interpretation independent of the representation."
>   [Source](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/01/19/nie/#sec-informationelements)

Also have a look at the [description of data objects](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/01/19/nie/v1.2/#sec-dataobjects)

So Method 2 is the way to go, to "apply" the different abstractions the ontology intends.